# Не получается скачать модуль pyttsx3: "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyttsx3

При написании кода `pip install pyttsx3` выводится вот такая ошибка

```
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'd:\python\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4vsiz5cf\\pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4vsiz5cf\\pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4vsiz5cf\pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4vsiz5cf\pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4vsiz5cf\pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge\setup.py", line 26, in <module>
        Extension(
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4vsiz5cf\pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge\pyobjc_setup.py", line 408, in Extension
        os_level = get_os_level()
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4vsiz5cf\pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge\pyobjc_setup.py", line 218, in get_os_level
        pl = plistlib.readPlist("/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist")
      File "d:\python\lib\plistlib.py", line 99, in readPlist
        with _maybe_open(pathOrFile, 'rb') as fp:
      File "d:\python\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "d:\python\lib\plistlib.py", line 82, in _maybe_open
        with open(pathOrFile, mode) as fp:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Уже скачал pywin32, pypiwin32, но все равно не получается хотя просто pyttsx скачался а pyttsx3 нет
   Взаранее спасибо!!!

Comment: Странно, зачем ему `pyobjc` это же под винду не пойдет. Поэтому и ошибка, т.к. путь `"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist"` не соответствует винде. Возможно это бага в библиотеке, тогда решение можно искать в репозитории либы, например в таких issue: https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/29 Кст, в той issue предлагался вариант установки старой версии: `pip install pyttsx3==2.71`. Попробуйте, только сначала удалите предыдущую версию: `pip uninstall pyttsx3`

Comment: спасибо вам огромное благодаря вам у меня все заработало

Comment: Здорово, что вам помогло, тогда, я оформлю как ответ

Answer (score 0):

Автору помогла установка старой версии библиотеки:

```
pip uninstall pyttsx3
pip install pyttsx3==2.71
```

---

Странно, зачем ему pyobjc это же под винду не пойдет. Поэтому и ошибка, т.к. путь `"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist"` не соответствует винде.

Возможно, это бага в библиотеке, тогда решение можно искать в репозитории либы, например в таких issue:

- https://github.com/nateshmbhat/pyttsx3/issues/29