# Ошибка при "pip install pyttsx3": "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pyttsx3

**Вот ошибка:**

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\никита\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe
' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\843E~1\\Ap
pData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3mylz4co\\pyobjc-framework-SyncServices\\setup.p
y'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\843E~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3mylz
4co\\pyobjc-framework-SyncServices\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'
"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.clos
e();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users
\843E~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3mylz4co\pyobjc-framework-SyncServices\pi
p-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\843E~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3mylz4co\pyobjc-fra
mework-SyncServices\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\843E~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3mylz4co\pyobjc-frame
work-SyncServices\setup.py", line 31, in <module>
        for fn in os.listdir("Modules")
      File "C:\Users\843E~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3mylz4co\pyobjc-frame
work-SyncServices\pyobjc_setup.py", line 408, in Extension
        os_level = get_os_level()
      File "C:\Users\843E~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3mylz4co\pyobjc-frame
work-SyncServices\pyobjc_setup.py", line 218, in get_os_level
        pl = plistlib.readPlist("/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plis
t")
      File "c:\users\никита\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\plistlib.
py", line 162, in readPlist
        with _maybe_open(pathOrFile, 'rb') as fp:
      File "c:\users\никита\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\contextli
b.py", line 82, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "c:\users\никита\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\plistlib.
py", line 120, in _maybe_open
        with open(pathOrFile, mode) as fp:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check th
e logs for full command output.
```

**Что делать?**

Comment: Посмотрите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1095411/201445

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло))

Comment: В версии 2.87 пофикшено.